# Login with password and facebook

Tags: oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth

I am in the process of designing an app that is supposed to let you login using either a username/password combination or facebook login. We have a custom OAuth server that uses user credentials to authenticate users. Now, the question is how to add facebook into this.

As I see it now, when the user wants to login with facebook, the client does all the work and gets the access token in the end. But how do we let our server know that this access token is a good one (and corresponds to a user in the database)? To me it seems like our OAuth server should be able to handle this as well, and I'm just missing the how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth supports different scenarios (flows). Client-does-all-the-work is so called "implicit" flow.

In your case it would be better to use authorization-code flow and extend your OAuth server. You put a "Facebook" button on your login page and instruct Facebook to redirect to a new special page on your OAuth server. Delivered authorization code then can be exchanged to the access token inside of your OAuth server and the server may issue its own session and tokens based on this.